Unexpected '__mul__' call during dot product
So, I have been trying to implement a basic Autograd and Neural Network from scratch using some numpy. This is the part of code of my AD which matters for this question which has been greatly shorten down for MRE. This is grad.py
from typing import Self
import numpy as np


class Variable:
   def __init__(self, value: np.ndarray=None):

      self.value = value if isinstance(value, np.ndarray) else np.asarray(value)
      self.prev = None

   def _variablify(self, x) -> Self:
      if not isinstance(x, Variable):
         x = Variable(x)

      return x
   
   def __add__(self, x) -> Self:      
      x = self._variablify(x)
      y = Variable(self.value + x.value)
      return y
   
   def __mul__(self, x) -> Self:
      x = self._variablify(x)
      y = Variable(self.value * x.value)
      return y
   
   __radd__ = __add__
   __rmul__ = __mul__

   def dot(self, x):
      x = self._variablify(x)
      y = Variable(self.value.dot(x.value))
      return y
   
   def __lt__(self, other):
      return self.value < other
   
   def __gt__(self, other):
      return self.value > other


def dot(a: Variable, b: Variable):
   return a.dot(b)

In the other file, main.py I try to implement a neural net
from typing import Self
import numpy as np

from grad import Variable
import grad

class Layer:
   def __init__(self, neurons: int):
      self.n_size = neurons
      self.activation = Variable(0)
   
   def previous(self, layer: Self):
      self.previous_layer = layer
      self.previous_layer.next_layer = self

   def next(self, layer: Self):
      self.next_layer = layer
      self.next_layer.previous_layer = self

   def initialise(self):
      self.weight_matrix = Variable(np.random.normal(0, 0.01, (self.n_size, self.next_layer.n_size)))
      self.bias_vector = Variable(np.random.normal(0, 0.01, (1, self.next_layer.n_size)))

      self.next_layer.x = grad.dot(self.activation, self.weight_matrix) + self.bias_vector
      self.next_layer.activation = np.where(self.next_layer.x > 0, self.next_layer.x, 0.01*self.next_layer.x)  #  Using LeakyReLU


if __name__ == "__main__":
   input_layer = Layer(5)
   input_layer.activation = Variable(np.random.randint(1, 5, (1,5)))

   h1 = Layer(3)
   h1.previous(input_layer)

   output = Layer(2)
   output.previous(h1)

   input_layer.initialise()
   h1.initialise()

   print(input_layer.activation, h1.activation, output.activation)

So, as you can see in the grad.py I had implemented the code for dot product wrapper. But now, here comes the error upon running the main.py file-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../main.py", line 62, in <module>
    h1.initialise()
  File ".../main.py", line 40, in initialise
    self.next_layer.x = grad.dot(self.activation, self.weight_matrix) + self.bias_vector
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".../grad.py", line 191, in dot
    return a.dot(b)
           ^^^^^^^^
  File ".../grad.py", line 49, in __mul__
    y = Variable(self.value * x.value)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,3) (3,2) 

Now to me, this is very strange. Because the error seems to tell us that a.dot(b) somehow called __mul__ which...it never did. I have absolutely no idea what is going on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

you're not asking things rights. the fact is that it did call __mul__, you should ask why. here your code and traceback have been too tampered with to be of any use. post the real ones

@folengateis Well, I know that but even while using this code which I posted here it still produces the same error. So I dont know why should I post a 200 line code when a MRE exists.

I don't believe it is an MRE as we cannot run the code without the grad import. Difficult to reproduce

Grad.py's MRE is literally in the question above, what are you talking about? I ran this exact code above (both grad and main) and I still get the same error.

Well that was my entire reason for this question afterall, that why in the hell did it randomly call to mul without an explanation. Because you see, the main.py code is almost the same but grad.py is shortened a lot. And the rest of grad.py is irrevant because we are not calculating gradients here, which is what the rest of the grad.py aside from this is pretty much all about. No calls relating to dot or mul

And anyways, this code literally produces the same error so why does it matter anyways? Try running it for yourself and see that it produces the same error regardless of whether its the full original code or not.

I see you are using type annotations. But apparently you aren't using a tool to enforce them like mypy. That's why they give you a sense of false security. It is true that def dot() is annotated to accept two Variables but you are not passing in two Variables. One of the parameters is a numpy array.
A call to mypy shows that this is the culprit:
self.next_layer.activation = np.where(self.next_layer.x > 0, self.next_layer.x, 0.01*self.next_layer.x)

You assign a numpy array to activation, but it is supposed and assumed to be a Variable
This explains the weird traceback. a.dot(b) is not calling your implementation, but numpy's instead. And numpy uses __mul__ on the array elements.
So you need to figure out how to fix the above line. And you really need to run mypy or something similar if you are using type hints.

Ah, I see. In fact I had seen it earlier, but I tried parsing it as a Variable but it brought up another ValueError so I just left it like this. But anyways, that is not my job to solve. Thanks for your answer. And yes, will definitely use mypy now.
